# What is the word for the metal things on boots where the laces go?

Tags: word-request

What are the metal parts of a boot where the laces are meant to go called? There are the circle parts and the hook parts. Do these have a different name each, or do they have the same name?

Answer (score 62):

The [Weinbrenner Shoe Company](http://www.theunionbootpro.com/anatomy.cfm) calls them *hook eyelets* and *set eyelets*:

[image: Diagram of various parts of a boot]

Comment: +1 for "hook eyelets." I've also seen them referred to as lace hooks.

Comment: "Set eyelets" are usually just "eyelets" (note the quotes in the figure).

Comment: "Set" Eyelets as opposed to loose eyelets.

Comment: Blucher? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hs5j8uUR2nc

Comment: [*What are you trying to figure out, B.D.? Who could I be? "What is a blucher!"*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110759/quotes/qt0398008)

Comment: Pull loop? Isn't it a... bootstrap?

Answer (score 47):

For shoes and other clothing and accessories, *[eyelet](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/eyelet)* is the common term:

> *noun [countable]* a small hole in cloth surrounded by a metal ring, for putting a string or rope through [Macmillan]

The more generic term is *[grommet](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/grommet)*, though in my experience this usually refers to a larger hole as might be used for a sail or tarpaulin.

Comment: +1 for **grommet**, which I was going to answer with.

Comment: In British English we'd normally use *eyelet* even for the big holes in tarpaulins.  *Grommet* is mainly used for a cable exit/strain relief part.

Comment: @ChrisH And also for an item implanted in the ear to relieve glue ear. You’ve apparently forgotten the War of Jennifer’s Ear.

Comment: @MikeScott I was too young to vote in 92 so had to Google it just now. The ear implant did occur to me but I left it out

Answer (score 15):

It is indeed an **eyelet** as others have answered. And the part of the lace that you push through the eyelet is called an **aglet** (the rigid plastic cylinder that binds the end of the lace).

Comment: *eyelet* : "1. a small round hole in leather or cloth for threading a lace, string, or rope through." - It's a grommet only if it has a grommet (a metal or leather ring).

Answer (score 10):

Definition [from the Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/eyelet):

> An **eyelet** is a small hole with a metal or leather ring around it in
>   cloth, for example, on a sail. You can put cord, rope, or string
>   through it.

Comment: Odd that the definition doesn't include a *plastic* ring. Plastic eyelets are common too